# Where can I find open source web application implementations online that contain (mostly) complete unit test suites in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, web-applications, junit, testng

I work for a large enterprise, and my team's unit test practices and coverage leave something to be desired.  I picked up copies of [xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code](http://amzn.com/0131495054) and [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://amzn.com/0131177052), but I would really like to see some full example test suites for existing applications. Specifically, I'm looking for the following:

- Open source (so I can look at the code and the test cases)
- The application under test is a web app.  (Not a web app framework.  I want to see something with some business logic in it.)
- Written in Java, so JUnit or TestNG are both fine.

I've dug around on [Github](https://github.com/search), but so far the vast majority of the Java apps I come across are Android apps or have no test suites.

Comment: You know that we can't release our company business logic as it violates our employment agreement and exposes company confidentiality.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this https://github.com/testinfected/petstore/ - it's a Spring/Hibernate pet store web app using the ideas in the http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/ book.